# How to send image using gcm in android?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project which will implement chat feature. I am using GCM to send message and working fine. But i want to send image just like facebook chat. After searching google i found that we can send image by encoding the image into base64 string. But the message size of gcm is up to 4kb so i can not send image like that. Here i need to upload the image into server and then needs to send the user a link and fetch the image from that link. But i think this will be a slow process . What can i do know?

I am sending message to others directly from my device using gcm. Please help me. I already found AirBop. But is there any other solution to send image?

Comment: First, I don't think that uploading to a server would be a slow process. On the other hand, is there anything else you can do? Maybe you can open a p2p connection between the devices, but I suspect that would be even slower.

Comment: but my server will face pressure if multiple user send image at a time and also it will cost huge memory in my server. Thats why i did not want to use server in that case.

Comment: No, it won't necessarily consume huge memory if IO is handled correctly. You should write the images straight to the disk while uploading. When done, you can send a message to the client, and they can download the image. If you do this all asynchronously (e.g. like Node.js), it will be even more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

you have to upload the image without GCM, On your server you have to had application  that read the file from your device (Via Socket), and return the URL of the saved image, then the device send a link via gcm (as text) the partner gets the link and download the image.